# How to pass list and variable to the thread pool?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

How should I pass multiple arguments specifically list and string variable to the threading pool:

```
def activate_item (list, object_id):
      do smth


thread_pool = ThreadPool(parallelism)

with open('examples/1000_PSOrthoTile_ids.txt') as f:
    item_ids = f.read().splitlines()[:400] # only grab 100

thread_pool.map(activate_item, item_ids)
```

How can I pass arguments to the Pool? I have reviewed several sources, but all mention both arguments as a list.

Comment: pass it in tuple inside list

Comment: if you have to send two values to function then you have to create list with pairs - `[ [data, id1], [data, id2], ....]` and use this list in `map` or rather in `starmap`

Comment: it would be simpler if you would create `minimal working code` with example data in code - so we could simply copy and run it - and use it to create example solution.

Comment: @furas ok, I passed tuple_data = [results, object_id]
    thread_pool = ThreadPool(4)
    thread_pool.map(process,tuple_data) and inside the function how should i process the list?

Comment: see my comment - it has to be list with sublists (pairs) but you have only one list - so you runs `function(results)` and `function(object_id)` instead of `function(results, id1)` `function(results, id2)`

Comment: It's unclear what object_id is. Is it the same value for every thread? If it is, you could use a *partial*

Comment: None of the posted answers resolves your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to send two values to function then you have to create list with pairs -

```
[ [data, id1], [data, id2], ....]
```

and use this list in `map()` or rather in `starmap()`

---

Minimal working code:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def activate_item(var1, var2):
    # create one string with '\n' to display it without strings from other theads
    print(f'var1: {var1} | var2: {var2}\n', end='')

pool = ThreadPool()

ids = [1,2,3,4,5]

data = [ (ids, x) for x in ids ] 

results = pool.starmap(activate_item, data)
```

Result:

```
var1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] | var2: 1
var1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] | var2: 2
var1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] | var2: 3
var1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] | var2: 4
var1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] | var2: 5
```

---

And if you use `map()` then you get all values as single list and you have to assign them to variables

```
def activate_item(all_vars):
    var1, var2 = all_vars
```

---

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def activate_item(all_vars):
    var1, var2 = all_vars
    # create one string with '\n' to display it without strings from other theads
    print(f'var1: {var1} | var2: {var2}\n', end='')

pool = ThreadPool()

ids = [1,2,3,4,5]

data = [ (ids, x) for x in ids ] 

results = pool.map(activate_item, data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to pass to your worker function, `activate_items`, two arguments: the complete `item_ids` list and an individual element from that list. If so, use `functools.partial`:

```py
from functools import partial

def activate_item (list, object_id):
      do smth


thread_pool = ThreadPool(parallelism)

with open('examples/1000_PSOrthoTile_ids.txt') as f:
    item_ids = f.read().splitlines()[:400] # only grab 100

thread_pool.map(partial(activate_item, item_ids), item_ids)
```